# From one to double integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and let $a\in (0,1)$. Prove that there exists a positive constant $c$ such that
$$\int_a^1\int_{x-a}^xf^2(s)dsdx\geq c\int_0^1f^2(s)ds.$$
I cannot see how I can prove it. Any ideas guys?. Thank you.

Comment: Swap the order of integration and consider the cases where $a > \frac{1}{2}$ and $a < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Jihad Munshi the constant c doesn't depend on f?